# Store previous session value and succeeding session values in array

Tags: php, x-cart

Hey there i have a shopping cart system and i'm trying to store every session value for each product added to the cart. unfortunately i can't seem to store all previous session value to an array and only the current session value is being stored. is the array being destroyed each time a new session is called?

here is the code for my session:

```
public function handleRequest()
{
    $sessionValue = $this->getCurrentProductId();
    if(!empty($sessionValue))
        {
           (int) \Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->session_value = $sessionValue;
        }

    // var_dump((int) \Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->session_value);
    parent::handleRequest();
}

public function getSessionValue()
{
    $id = array();
    $count = array();
    $id = \Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->id;
    $count = (int)\Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->session_value;
    $arr=[ 
            "id" => $id,
            "Item_id" => $count
         ];
    //array_push($arr);
    \Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->id = $id + 1;
    (int)\Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->session_value = $count;
    return json_encode($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you create a new array each request by doing this

```
 $id = array();
    $count = array();
```

then you don't push the value to the array ,you destroy it by assigning a single value to it with this:

```
$id = \Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->id;
    $count = (int)\Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->session_value;
```

finally you use an empty array coming from nowhere to store your value like  this:

```
$arr=[ 
            "id" => $id,
            "Item_id" => $count
         ];
```

and you even try to push this array in itself:

```
  //array_push($arr);
```

it will throws error if you uncomment this line as $arr doesn't exist
finally you make some assignation and return $arr which will contain exclusively the new session data

```
\Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->id = $id + 1;
(int)\Xlite\Core\Session::getInstance()->session_value = $count;
return json_encode($arr);
```

clearly you build a new array each time.You must use another approach example create an object or an array containing your data ,  serialize it and save it somewhere.Then you will be able to unserialize it when needed,push the new values ,serialize it and store it again for the next time.One more  thing we  push a new value to array this way:

```
$array[]='your value here' ;
//or 
array_push($array,your value);
//or by even using
//an inexisting index
$array['notexists']=your value;
```